Optional chaining doesn't satisfy TS on objects (type guard)
type Obj1 = {
  url: 'coolurl.com'
}

type Obj2 = {
  src: 'someurl.com'
}

function SomeComponent(item: Obj1 | Obj2) {
  return (
    <img src={item?.url || item?.src} />
  )
}

Result:
Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Obj1 | Obj2'.
  Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Obj2'

Desired:
no error as optional chaining satisfies the type guard.
I believe something like ("url" in item) or same-line type assertion may help but the size of the component renders these options tedious.

Tedious or not, TS is this way on purpose and you'll need to work around it with such methods. You could try to widen to an exclusive union, shown in the answer below, and you can do it programmatically with something like ExclusifyUnion shown here, and in this playground link so it should be less tedious for large unions.

This is a pretty typical pattern in TS.  With optional chaining TS has no idea which type is which.
function SomeComponent(item: Obj1 | Obj2) {
  return (
    <img src={"url" in item ? item.url : item.src} />
  )
}

If you really really find using "xx" in obj too tedious, you could define Obj1 and Obj2 as a discriminated union like so.
type Obj1 = {
  url: 'coolurl.com'
  src?:undefined
}

type Obj2 = {
  src: 'someurl.com'
  url?:undefined
}

function SomeComponent(item: Obj1 | Obj2) {
    
  return (
    <img src={ item.src ?? item.url} />
  )
}



Thanks, I was afraid of this. There are probably 2 dozen places where I have to satisfy TS and sometimes nested :grimace: so I will try out the discriminated union.

You can use type predicate to narrow the type when needed, for example in your code you can create a function that narrows the item to one of the two types: Playground
type Obj1 = {
  url: 'coolurl.com'
}

type Obj2 = {
  src: 'someurl.com'
}

function isObj1(obj: Obj1 | Obj2): obj is Obj1 {
    return (obj as Obj1).url !== undefined;
}

function SomeComponent(item: Obj1 | Obj2) {
  return (
    <img src={isObj1(item) ? item.url : item.src} />
  )
}

